# What does it take to get suspended?

Tags: support

I've seen quite a few experienced veterans getting suspended recently on Ask Ubuntu...  As I'm an old, grouchy, grumpy, cranky geek, ***I'm starting to get worried...***

Is this a new script running that proactively gives everyone a "suspend score" and when the threshold is met just bans someone?

Or will we still be contacted by a human first and only get suspended under the "Three strikes and you're out" regime?

*What <s>the hell</s> is going on???*

[image: I'm genuinely worried now!]

Comment: Why does this (valid) question receive (currently) five downvotes ? I'm having absolutely no idea ... anyway : +1 from me for the grouchy, grumpy, cranky "old fart" and ... +1 for the answer from @terdon he accepted. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thank you!  **:-)**

Comment: +1 from me as well. I'm not sure what users you are referring to but I suspect I know of one. Your question doesn't single people out (neither does the answer) so it seems like a good question to me :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing new going on. Users are suspended when they do things that are in blatant violation of the site's rules. And yes, a suspension will always be given out by a human and you have the ability to respond to the human.

The mods, and SE, do not give suspensions lightly over nothing. I cannot discuss the details of any specific suspension, but I can tell you that when someone is suspended, everyone on the mod team is made aware of it and the suspension is usually (except in blatant cases where a discussion isn't even needed) discussed by multiple mods and we decide what to do together.

So you can rest assured that when you see a suspension, there have *always* been humans involved in that decision. You can also rest assured that the mod team is either behind the suspension or, in the case of network-wide suspensions which can only be doled out by SE staff, aware of it and in agreement with it.

Comment: [Phew!](https://s14-eu5.startpage.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=https:%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2Ff2%2F3f%2F3b%2Ff23f3ba46b96721c07983c96c2b03c07.png&sp=434217c3b93206263daa59818596dd27)  **;-)**